# Split single VARCHAR field with many values, and insert them separately

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm migrating an old database data to a new one, and they used to store telephone numbers in the following format:
**Example 1:**

```
41.9044-9082;41.9044-9661;41.9851-9862;41.9984-0393;41.3399-9169;41.3997-7999;
```

**Example 2:**

```
41.3369-0102;41.8928-5992;
```

**No telephones(empty):**

```
;
```

How can I split these single VARCHAR fields with many values, and insert them separately?
**Table example of how it is:**

```
|#id_tel#|### number ####|#|client_id|#|
|#  1   #|111163;3554353;|#|   2     |#|
|#  2   #|222222;        |#|   3     |#|
|#  3   #|;              |#|   4     |#|
```

**Table example of how I would like it to be:**

```
|#id_tel#|### number ####|#|client_id|#|
|#  1   #|111163         |#|   2     |#|
|#  2   #|3554353        |#|   2     |#|
|#  3   #|222222         |#|   3     |#|
```

Comment: Couple of questions: Are you trying to update back to the same table or copy to another table? Does it have to be in MySQL or can you script it (PERL, PHP, etc.) How many rows are you dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with nested calls of SUBSTRING_INDEX() and a numbers table. In my example I create the numbers table on the fly for up to 100 numbers.

Assuming a table old_tel with following CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE old_tel (
    id_tel INT,
    `number` VARCHAR(200),
    client_id INT
);
```

you get the splitted numbers with the client_id with this query:

```
  SELECT
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`number`, ';', n.n), ';', -1) value,
      client_id
  FROM 
      old_tel
  CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 
          1 + a.N + b.N * 10 AS n
      FROM
          (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
          ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
      ORDER BY n      
  ) n
  WHERE
      n.n <= LENGTH(`number`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`number`, ';', ''))
  AND
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`number`, ';', n.n), ';', -1) <> ''
  ORDER BY
     client_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`number`, ';', n.n), ';', -1);
```

Assuming your new telephone numbers table looks nearly the same:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tel (
    id_tel INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `number` VARCHAR(200),
    client_id INT
);
```

you can fill this table with this simple `INSERT` statement using the first query:

```
  INSERT INTO new_tel (`number`, client_id)
  SELECT
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`number`, ';', n.n), ';', -1) value,
      client_id
  FROM 
      old_tel
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
        1 + a.N + b.N * 10 AS n
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
        ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n    
  ) n
  WHERE
    n.n <= LENGTH(`number`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`number`, ';', ''))
  AND
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`number`, ';', n.n), ';', -1) <> ''
  ORDER BY
     client_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`number`, ';', n.n), ';', -1);
```

## Explanation

The inner subselect with the UNION ALL creates on the fly a numbers table. We restrict this on the number of substrings in the `number` column and filter out empty values.

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`number`, ';', n.n), ';', -1) value
```

cuts out the n-th number that is separated by semicolon.

See it working in this <kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93e5e/1)</kbd>

**Note: ** This is very fast by avoiding agonizing row by row inserts.